# Add Listener into ViewHolder for fragement to communication with Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

I am trying to trigger the start of a fragment B when a click is detected on an item from the Recycler view present in the Fragment A.

The way I did it is:

- MainActivity start the Fragement A and display a list of CardView
- Once the user click on one of the CardView, an interface call a click method implemented in the main Activity to start the Fragment B

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnLocationSelectedListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if(savedInstanceState == null) { // initial transaction should be wrapped like this
            --Start Fragment A
        }
    }

    override fun onLocationSelected(id: String) {
        replaceFragment(FragmentB(), R.id.listcontainer, id)
    }

    companion object {
        val LOCATION_ID: String = "location_id"
    }
}
```

The interface is defined in : OnLocationSelectedListener.kt

```
interface OnLocationSelectedListener {
    fun onLocationSelected(id: String)
}
```

the listener must be called from the Adapter linked to Fragment B

```
class FragmentBAdapter(

    var listOfLocations: List<RestaurantLocation>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationsListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var onLocationSelectedListener: OnLocationSelectedListener


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listOfLocations.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocationsListAdapter.ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            parent.context,
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.location_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindViewHolder(listOfLocations[position])
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(private val context: Context, private val viewDataBinding: LocationItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewDataBinding.root) {

        fun bindViewHolder(location: RestaurantLocation) {
            viewDataBinding.locationName.text = location.name
            viewDataBinding.cardItem.setOnClickListener {
                onLocationSelectedListener.onLocationSelected(location.id)
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I have an exception popping up because `lateinit property onLocationSelectedListener has not been initialized`

I do not understand how to initialize it?

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the listener to the constructor of your FragmentBAdapter, like so:

```kotlin
class FragmentBAdapter(val onLocationSelectedListener: OnLocationSelectedListener)
```

Your Activity is a OnLocationSelectedListener, so in your Fragment where you create your adapter, probably in `onCreateView()`, you can just do this

```kotlin
adapter = FragmentBAdapter(activity as? OnLocationSelectedListener)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have onLocationSelectedListener's implementation in your MainActivity, you can pass MainActivity's object to FragmentBAdapter and initialize onLocationSelectedListener in FragmentBAdapter's constructor by MainActivity Object